# Как установить CryptoPro в Idea, чтобы при запуске UI теста возможно было использовать сертификаты?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, chromedriver, selenoid

Как возможно поставить CryptoPro в проект в IDEA? Задача запустить ui тест, где в браузере присутствует расширение КриптоПро ЭЦП Browser plug-in и его можно использовать для подписи нужных файлов или других функций. Это необходимо для автотестов. Возможно это делается в каких то конфигах, но конкретику нет.

Если кто-то сталкивался с данном проблемой, то буду очень благодарен за информацию.

Читал инструкцию из интернета скачал "ЖТЯИ.00101-02 96 02. Руководство программиста. JavaCSP.pdf", но для старта нужной информации не нашел, либо плохо искал.

На самом сайте криптопро полезностей об этом не нашел.

Возможное решение проблемы, но не факт. Что думаете?

```
public class CryptoProTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Установите путь к драйверу браузера (например, ChromeDriver).
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "путь_к_драйверу/chromedriver");

        // Создайте объект опций для браузера.
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        // Укажите путь к директории с расширением CryptoPro.
        options.addExtensions(new File("путь_к_CryptoPro_расширению.crx"));

        // Создайте экземпляр WebDriver с опциями.
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        // Теперь браузер запущен с установленным расширением CryptoPro.
        // Вы можете использовать его для проведения тестовых действий.
    }
}
```

Также есть мысль добавить файл самого криптопро, если найдется нужный. Такой пример:

```
chromeOptions.addExtensions(new File("src/main/resources/файл.crx"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в инете файлик загрузки приложения на локальную машину в формате .crx и ее добавил в папку resources на своем проекте.

Далее добавил настройки в класс драйвер менеджер.

```
chromeOptions.addExtensions(new File("src/main/resources/название.crx"));
```

Comment: Но это конечно мелкая часть того, что нужно сделать в selenoid. В данном вопросе рассматривал именно расширение в браузер.